# Graph.js page not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

Can anyone help me please? I have created a graph.js page and it doesn't show a graph. Here is the javascript:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.sql, "data/Recipes_MySql.sql")
  .await(makeGraphs);

function makeGraphs(error, recipeData) {
  var ndx = crossfilter(recipeData);
  show_recipe_balance(ndx);
  dc.renderAll();
}

function show_recipe_balance(ndx) {
  var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('countryorigin'));
  var group = dim.group();

  dc.barChart("#recipe-balance")
    .width(400)
    .height(300)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(group)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .xAxisLabel("Country")
    .yAxis().ticks(20);
}
```

I have an error saying that:

> d3 is not defined, please fix or add /* global d3*/

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You have to include the D3 library on whatever page you want to use it on. In what environment are you running this code, I assume in the browser?

Comment: I am running it in the browser.

Comment: set a `script` tag for d3 before your dc.js `script` tag